# Multiple versions of R installed but can't locate or remove the old one

Tags: r

I have downloaded and installed R.

I see it here in Applications folder (I am on a Mac with Yosemite):

[image]

Fine. I can launch R.app and indeed, yes, I am running the version I want, which is 3.2.2:

[image]

So far so good. I can even open up RStudio and see that I am indeed running 3.2.2!

[image]

So after all this, I simply go to my terminal, type 
`r`
and turns out I am running 3.1.1!

[image]

I understand the old user of my work computer probably had installed this older version.

So here's what I'm wondering:

- If I just installed R.app correctly, WHY is this old version still living on my computer, and how do I get rid of it?
- If this is some sort of $PATH thing, WHY doesn't the most obvious location for an app, the Applications folder, get checked for the existence of R?

Thanks.

*UPDATE* 
Turns out the old version of R has been installed by homebrew.

Comment: `which r` or `which r.cmd` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing `which r` in your terminal will give you where the shell thinks R is. Then, you need only uninstall it from that location.

Since we've determined it's homebrew, all you need to do now is `brew unlink r; rm -Rf /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1` and you should be golden after you `rehash` in your shell.

It worked because you installed it using homebrew. To remove it from the system, you must first `unlink` it and then `remove` it from the system.

Comment: what do you see, though?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/[rR]`?

Comment: do you mean `hash -r`?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a brief explanation. If you need more help, let me know and I'll try to dig into homebrew further.

Comment: macports doesn't use /usr/local/Cellar @smci

Comment: I didn't say it did. I'm saying *"Consider also the general case where you might have other installs (e.g. macports)"*